# create vtiger module

Tags: module, vtiger

Can you give me a hand? I could't create vtiger 5.1 module, can't find any examples.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the vtlib api to create a new module.

Check this link for vtlib documentation.

http://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtiger_CRM_5_Developer_Guide/VTLIB

Answer (score 0):

follow this how to create entity module
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/CreatingEntityModule

by just
1) unzip Payslip-5.1.0-package.zip
2) zip up the "manifest.xml" and "modules" folder containing Payslip
3) import it to vtiger via vtiger's ModuleManager

Then everything works.